# Этимология слова "храм"

Tags: этимология

Какова этимология слова "храм"?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

**У Шанского**

ХРАМ. Заимств. из ст.-сл. яз. См. хоромы. Общеслав. *chormъ > храмъ с появлением неполногласия. Исходно — "дом вообще", затем — "церковь".

ХОРОМЫ. Общеслав. Форма мн. ч. от xopoм < *hormъ (> хором после возникновения полногласия и утраты слабого ъ), родств. др.-в.-нем. scirm "защита, заслон", др.-инд. cármen "шкура, кожа".

**У Черных**

Черных считает, что полной ясности в происхождении общеславянской основы этого слова нет. Он предполагает, что общеслав. chormъ происходит из ksor-m, а **и.-е. корень (s)kor - резать (родственные слова: кора, короткий, скорняк, шкура)**. Перестановка sk/ks/kch происходила в дальнейем не на всей праславянской территории, а только в ее юго-восточной части.

Тогда исходное значение слова "хоромы" - это нечто срезанное: навес, защита, заслон

Answer (score 1):

Происходит от церк.-слав., ст.-слав. храмъ, при исконнорусск. хоромъ (см. хоро́мы)

Фасмер.

И что удивительно, ни Черных, ни даже оригинал Шанский не возражают, а все чего-то еще спорят.

Comment: Слово "хоромы" тоже имеет семантику "дом", "строение" - но в данном смысле не абы какое, а достойное божества. Поэтому -  Дом, с заглавной буквы.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такая версия:
Ранние христианские храмы располагались в пещерах и римских катакомбах:
храм < χηραμός "нора, логово, пещера" [Hom., Arst., Babr., Plut].
Самый известный храм - Пещера Рождества, где родился Иисус Христос от Девы Марии. http://trueview.livejournal.com/18935.html

Хоромы, хоромина - древний обратный переход в "полногласие".

Answer (score 0):

"Храм" может быть от арабского "харам"—запрещенный, запретный. Самый известный храм в Исламе—Масджид ал-Харам (Запретная Мечеть).

Comment: Вам запретили бывать в храме?

Comment: Каким образом мусульманский арабский храм мог стать основой для христианского слова?

Comment: "Каким образом мусульманский арабский храм мог стать основой для христианского слова" - а от общих источников, вестимо... Зрите в корень и не ошибётесь :)

Answer (score -1):

Слово "храм" происходит от слов "хранить", "хранилище". Изначально храмами на Руси обозначались места хранения и передачи из поколения в поколение определенных знаний и культуры. Слово "хоромы" также означало "кладовую знаний". Отсюда и поговорка - "Чужие хоромы - потёмки".

Comment: @ user180293 Источник желательно привести.

Answer (score -1):

Не в коем случае не может быть ХРАМ=ХРАНИЛИЩЕМ,потому что ХРАНИЛИЩЕ от ХРАНить,а не ХРАМить.Корень слова различен.
Если-же происхождение слова ХРАМ от слова ХОРОМЫ,то в этом случае здесь имеет месть быть корень "ХОР","собор"("собираться")- тому подтверждение.

Comment: Обращайте внимание на подчёркивание текстового редактора! Это его сигналы вам о допущенных вами min 10 ошибках. Не следует торопиться тем более, что вопрос задавался полтора года  тому назад.